# Erratic/Unrhythmic idling sound

Tags: suzuki, rough-idle, hunting-idle, ritz

This is a Suzuki Ritz (Splash) 2011 DDIS Diesel car. When the car is started fresh in the morning, the idling sound is not rhythmic. It varies its slow-speed, say every other second. I have uploaded the audio of the idling sound of the engine below. The difference is ever so slightly differentiable.

- [Fresh Start in the morning](https://soundcloud.com/subin-sebastian/idling-on-fresh-start)
- [After Running for some time](https://soundcloud.com/subin-sebastian/idling-after-a-few-hours-of)

Besides, the ignition is long, takes a few seconds for the engine to get started in the morning. Battery problem? (There is no service warning light turned on once the engine has started up)

**UPDATES**

1. (19-July-2019) I have replaced the battery, and the long ignition problem is resolved now.
2. (7-August-2019) The engine now consistently stalls by itself, if I throttle it high for a few seconds, and releases the throttle.
3. (11-August-2019) A mechanic suggested, and a forum pointed out that a clogged EGR valve may cause erratic idling. [Link](https://www.team-bhp.com/forum/diy-do-yourself/179361-diy-egr-valve-cleaning-1-3l-ddis-mjd.html).

Comment: Is there a power loss parallel to the intermittent sound? It might be not working or bad piston.

Comment: I don't feel any apparent power loss, but not sure.

Comment: Could this be an injector problem?

Comment: Another question is, if this is a bad piston problem, how it is idling fine after some time of running.

Comment: More possibly injector problem rather than a piston. Does it stall on its own?

Comment: It doesn't stall on its own yet. Another possibility I have in my mind is about bad battery earthing. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Battery related problem might be the reason for long ignition as I agree.

Comment: I have replaced the battery, idle is still not rhythmic.

Comment: What is the weather like where you live?

Comment: It's about 21°C in the mornings, goes upto 27°C in the noon. The long ignition problem is resolved after the battery was replaced.

Comment: It started stalling by itself.